# Merging array into specific element of another multi array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have first array that looks like such:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [data] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [type] => asset 
                [description] => Real Estate
                [value] => 350000
            )
    )
)
```

A second array looks like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [owners] => Array
            (
                [data] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 1
                        [percentage] => 100
                    )
            )
    )
)
```

I need to insert the 2nd array into the first at the level of 'data' so it looks like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [data] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [type] => asset 
                [description] => Real Estate
                [value] => 350000
                [owners] => Array
                (
                    [data] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [percentage] => 100
                        )
                )
            )
    )
)
```

I've tried array_merge, but the output is not as I expect.  A normal appending of the 2nd array to first just adds it outside the scope of the first.

Can anyone advise how I would add the 2nd at the level displayed above ?
thx

Comment: Please show us the relevant code, it will make it much easier to determine what the issue is.

Comment: `$array1[0]['data']['owners'] = $array2[0]['owners']`

Comment: $array1[0]['data']['owners'] = $array2[0]['owners']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php 
    $array1 = Array("0" => Array("data" => Array( "id" => "1", "type" => "asset", "description" => "Real Estate", "value" => "350000" ) ) );

    $array2 = Array( "0" => Array ( "owners" => Array( "data" => Array( "id" => "1", "percentage" => "100") ) ) );

    // try this
    $array1[0]['data']['owners'] = $array2[0]['owners'];

    echo "<pre>"; print_r($array1);
?>
```

This will give output as

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [type] => asset
                    [description] => Real Estate
                    [value] => 350000
                    [owners] => Array
                        (
                            [data] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 1
                                    [percentage] => 100
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

[See Working link](http://ideone.com/WCTIN2)